# tkinter: press button to get its own grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

I am trying to create a column of buttons which when they are pressed, the grid that down a row show pop up another two buttons.

```
for i in tlist:
    opl.append(Tk.Button(self.frame, width = 12 , text=i[3],command = lambda:self.pressedop(i[2], a)))
    opl[a].grid(row=a, column=0, columnspan=2)
    a = a + 1
```

That successfully create a column of buttons, with `text(i[3])` correctly shown, but when a button is pressed, `i[2]` will be last button's info, and a will be last button's row +1.

Is there a way which I can pass the `i[2]` and it's own `grid_info` down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question, but you can use widget.grid_forget() to remove a widget from the geometry manager.  If you then want it in a different row, just widget.grid() with the new row and column.  A simple example

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

from functools import partial

opl = []
top = tk.Tk()

def move_it(num):
    for ctr in range(num, 5):
        opl[ctr].grid_forget()   
        opl[ctr].grid(row=6, column=ctr)

for but_num in range(5):
    opl.append(tk.Button(top, width = 12 , text=str(but_num),
               command = partial(move_it, but_num)))
    opl[-1].grid(row=but_num, column=0, columnspan=2)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: My concern was on how `lambda:self.pressedop(a,b)` can store its own info rather than just show the last assignment for `a` and `b`, partial somehow freeze the variable and hence did the job. [link](http://i.imgur.com/6RjgRMG.png) is the result anyway.

Comment: Guido wanted to remove lambda, reduce(), filter() and map() constructs in Python3.X but was convinced otherwise because of conversion, backward compatibility, and the many, many opinions when coming up with better replacements.  I find that many are confused with the lambda syntax so use partial as it is straight forward to use.